# Angularjs Button loading state directive with ng-disabled directive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to reconcile using the following directive for changing a button's loading state via bootstrap js plugin:

```
.directive("btnLoading", function() {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(function() {
        return scope.$eval(attrs.btnLoading);
    }, function(loading) {
        if (loading)
            return element.button("loading");
        element.button("reset");
    });
};
```

This is working quite well as it controls the state of the button when necessary and adds the loading text as advertised.  The issue I am running into is that when this directive is applied to a button as well as utilizing ng-disabled when the form is not valid, the button is enabled and not disabled as it should/used to be before I applied this directive to the button.  My ng-disabled on the button is just:

```
ng-disabled="form.$invalid"
```

Is there a way to reconcile these two directives so the disabled state is not reset within the loading directive?

**EDIT**
Based on your suggestion I ended up with the following code:

```
   .directive("btnLoading", function () {
       return function (scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.$watch(function () {
               return scope.$eval(attrs.ngDisabled);
           }, function (newVal) {
               //you can make the following line more robust
               if (newVal) {
                   return;
               } else {
                   return scope.$watch(function () {
                       return scope.$eval(attrs.btnLoading);
                   },

                   function (loading) {
                       if (loading) return element.button("loading");
                       element.button("reset");
                   });
               }
           });
       };
   })
```

I had to use a function to watch for changes on eval of ng-disabled otherwise it would only return the function of what it needed to evaluate for changes, not the value/changed value.  Additionally then I added the watch for the btn loading to watch for the click/save event and once that changes then set the loading state.  Not sure if this is the best option but that was the only working code I could figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `ng-disabled` property in the parent's scope, and if it is disabled then just simply does nothing.

The trick is to watch on `ngdisabled` property like this

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngDisabled, function (newVal) {...
```

I want to shed some light on since I can't test your code without other pieces, you probably can do something like this:

```
.directive("btnLoading", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        //maybe you need just scope.$watch instead of scope.$parent.$watch. Depends on your impl.
        scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.ngDisabled, function (newVal) {

            //you can make the following line more robust
            if (newVal === 'disabled' || newVal === 'true') return;

            function () {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.btnLoading);
            },

            function (loading) {
                if (loading) return element.button("loading");
                element.button("reset");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you take a look at my edit and make sure this looks ok or if I could reduce the code?

Comment: Mine does yes, yours did not work and logging out some of the vars I got it figured out.  I just wanted to see if that was the best option with the added callback and scope watch.

Comment: Oh cool. I just wanted to shed some light on since I can't test your code without other pieces. The key is to use ` scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.ngDisabled...`. I am glad you can figure it out.

Comment: You can also have a look at this implementation, seems more readable for me: https://gist.github.com/thisboyiscrazy/5137781.