# Angularjs Button loading state directive within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am looking to expand upon a previously resolved question:

[Angularjs Button loading state directive with ng-disabled directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019963/angularjs-button-loading-state-directive-with-ng-disabled-directive)

This directive is working perfectly for a button based upon a single instance, however when applied within an ng-repeat, all of the buttons created change their state when one button is clicked.  Is there a way to make this directive work so that when this directive is applied to multiple buttons within an ng-repeat, only the button clicked changes its loading state?

I created a plunker to demonstrate what the problem is: http://plnkr.co/edit/epdPhwx27RlthzLPXf67?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with your same plunker.

[Button-Loading Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K58w8rLqRXUk5Xg7X8d2?p=preview)

I changed the way you looked at the data. Notice $scope.array, and $scope.load, as well as the data found in the button element.

Comment: Although that particular way works, I used a super simplified example to demonstrate the concept.  I updated the example with a more complex set of close to actual data I am using.  My thinking on this is I want it to be compatible across the application using various data sets and I don't think it works well enough adding in a n individual loading object property for each one.

Comment: @Brian I updated my plunker to work with yours. Check it out.

Comment: I see that, although you are still just appending a property on to the objects within the controller, I guess I thought there would be a way of doing this all within the directive utilizing its isolate scope with only a single property defined in the controller?

Comment: If you want to keep your controller cleaner, you could define a custom directive bound to a click event to run your load() method. Then you would just not use ng-click.

Comment: This ended up being the best option, however instead of adding a separate array, I appended a value to the specific object so when they are in a sortable list reordering them doesn't screw things up.